# Testing MultipartForm with multiple file inputs.

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, jmock

I am using Playframework 2.1 with Scala.
I would like to  test my function , in view part i have to input files. image and music.
I am able to test just musicfile perfectly but when it comes to test both of them. I am having java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1.
I think the problem is defining the multipartformfilesdata. I tried to create a list of fileparts.

```
val data = new MultipartFormData(
  Map(
    "checkbox" -> Seq("test-1"),
    "tracktitle" -> Seq("test-1"),
    "releasename" -> Seq("test-1"),
    "trackartist" -> Seq("test-1"),
    "tracksubtitle" -> Seq("test-1"),
    "tracklabel" -> Seq("test-1"),
    "releaseartist" -> Seq("test-1"),
    "releasegenre" -> Seq("test-1"),
    "releasesubtitle" -> Seq("test-1"),
    "releaselabel" -> Seq("test-1"),
    "select" -> Seq("1"),
    "format" -> Seq("SINGLE"),
    "trackgenre" -> Seq("test-1")),
  List(FilePart("musicFile", "musicFile", Some("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"), play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile(new java.io.File("/tmp/pepe.txt"))),
      FilePart("imageFile","imageFile",Some("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"), play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile(new java.io.File("/tmp/pepe.txt")))),        
  List(),
  List())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can test it like that first one is fileparts , second one is missingFileparts, third one is badFileParts